# Add sin wave to triangle mesh

Tags: opengl

can someone help me addd a sin wave onto my triangle mesh to help me get a wave effect.

```
for(int i = 0; i<150; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<150; j++){
            grid[i][j] = 0;
            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
                glVertex3f(i*3,grid[i][j],j*3);
                glVertex3f(i*3,grid[i][j],j*3+3);
                glVertex3f(i*3+3,grid[i][j],j*3);
            glEnd();
            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
                glVertex3f(i*3,grid[i][j],j*3+3);
                glVertex3f(i*3+3,grid[i][j],j*3+3);
                glVertex3f(i*3+3,grid[i][j],j*3);
            glEnd();
        }

    }
```

If i've got it right, all i should need to do is add a sin value to grid[i][j], am i right?
Are all the y values to be set to the same grid[i][j]?

Comment: Just try, see what you get and whether or not the result makes any sense to you? And if it doesn't try to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Are you trying to set up a surface that when looked on edge it looks like a sine wave?
If that is the case then assuming that you are modulating the y-axis and the z-axis plays no effect then you need to determine the frequency you want to use.
i.e y = A * sine (w * x + p) where A is amplitude, w is angular frequency, and p is phase.

You will also have to take into account the number of sample points on the x-axis so that it doesn't look to aliased.  Sine is a continuous function but you are take only 150 samples.

Also you may want to reconsider how to calculate and draw your final triangle mesh.  Your current code is not the most efficient because you are recalculating your mesh every frame.
You may want to consider initializing grid and then drawing triangle strips, etc.  There is a lot online that discusses that.